# How to create a two tone banner in bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, sass

I am trying to create a banner that has a two tone blue color similar to this: [image: Banner]

I am using `Bootstrap 4.x` with `asp.net mvc`. I have tried dividing the banner into 3 columns but I couldn't expand the the background color all the way in the icon column.

Here is how it currently looks on my end:
[image]

Here is my code:

#### View

```cs
<div class="row alert-banner-row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 icon-column">
            <i class="fas fa-3x @Model.Icon1 fa-inverse"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 body-column">
            <h5>@Model.Title</h5>
            <p>@Model.Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 button-column">
            @if (Model.ButtonUrl.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                <a class="ctaBanner-cta button button--white" target="_blank" href="@Model.ButtonUrl">@Model.ButtonLabel</a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a class="ctaBanner-cta button button--white" href="@Model.ButtonUrl">@Model.ButtonLabel</a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### SCSS

```
.alert-banner-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #004089;

    .body-column {
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        margin: 0rem;
        color: white;
    }

    .icon-column {
        background-color: #00336D;
    }
}
```

How can I edit what I currently have to make it look like the first screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the darker background on your `.icon-column`, its parent `.alert-banner-row` cannot have any padding. Otherwise it would show a gap:

```html
<div class="row alert-banner-row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 icon-column">
        <i />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 body-column">
        <h5 />
        <p />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 button-column">
        <a />
    </div>
</div>
```

And to show the left corner, you would need to specify `overflow:hidden;` otherwise it won't be shown as it's covered by its overflow content.

```css
.alert-banner-row {
    background-color: #004089;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;

    .body-column {
        padding-top: 1rem;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .icon-column,
    .button-column {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .icon-column {
        background-color: #00336D;
    }
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/krdu6wjc/53/

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the columns `display:flex` and `align-items: center` instead...

```
.alert-banner-row {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #004089;

    .body-column {
        padding-top: 10px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        margin: 0rem;
        color: white;
        align-self: center;
    }

    .icon-column {
        background-color: #00336D;
        text-align: center;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .button-column {
        align-self: center;
    }
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/wJMhKZ7P7y

Comment: In your codeply the icon's background doesn't fully fill. There are some spacings between the icon div and the  main row div

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Please clarify the question. If you mean the first column in too wide, then make it `col-sm-1` instead of `col-sm-2`

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.0-11/css/all.min.css">

    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="height:100px;color: white;">
            <div class="col-2" style="background-color: #00336D;">
                <div style="text-align: center; position: relative; top:40%;">
                    <i class=" fa fa-exclamation-circle "></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-8 " style=" background-color: #004089;padding: 2%; ">
                <h1><b>Creative Writing</b></h1>
                Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears. This forces the writer to use creativity
                to complete one of three common writing challenges. The writer can use the paragraph as the first one of a short story and build upon it.
            </div>
            <div class=" col-2 " style=" background-color: #004089; " ">
                    <button type=" button " class=" btn btn-primary align-content-center " style=" background-color: white; color:#00336D ;position:relative;top:30% "><b>Click Here</b></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js "></script>
        <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

check it:
https://jsfiddle.net/s9qmj1fn/